# Python3 - Pytest directory structure and imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest

I have the following project files (using Python3):

```
pyproj
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── module1.py
├── module2.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_module.py
```

module1 contains no imports.

module2 imports from module 1 as follows:

```
import module1
```

main.py imports from module1 and module2 as follows:

```
from module1 import *
from module2 import *
```

I would like tests/test_module to be able to import from module2 and from module1, and to be able to run it using `pytest` from the `pyproj` directory. However attempting to import module2 using:

```
 from ..module2 import *
```

causes the following error when running `pytest` from either the `pyproj` directory or the `tests` directory:

`tests/test_module.py:1: in <module>
    from ..module2 import *
module2.py:1: in <module>
    import module1
E   ImportError: No module named 'module1'`

The problem seems to be when module1 is importing module2. `python3 main.py` runs correctly however.

I've tried numerous changes, but none seem to allow both `main.py` and the tests to work correctly. What is the correct way to structure the project and appropriately import files to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute import: `from module2 import *` in tests and configure PYTHONPATH to pyproj before running tests. Or run tests in virtual env with pyproj installed. Or use tox which creates such venvs for you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution may not be best practice, but works, after a bit of experimenting:

- use from myproj.module2 import something
- make PYTHONPATH include myproj
- use **init**.py in tests directory

My experiment repo is here: https://github.com/epogrebnyak/question-package-structure-for-testing/tree/master/which