# What is the proper way to structure python3 code and imports that works for both tests and running the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am relatively new to python, and I am struggling to find a combination of file hierarchy and import statements that will work in pycharm, pytest on the command line, running the actual program on the command line, and building in bamboo.

Here is my hierarchy:

```
foo
| goo
| __init__.py
| run.py
  | koo
    | __init__.py
    | bar.py
  | loo
    | __init__.py
    | baz.py
| tests
| __init__.py
| test_bar.py
| test_baz.py
| test_file.py
| data
  | text.txt
```

Here is my code:

foo/goo/koo/bar.py:

```
greeting = "hello"


def hello():
    return greeting
```

foo/goo/loo/baz.py:

```
from koo import bar


def greet():
    return "the greeting is..." + bar.hello()
```

foo/goo/run.py:

```
import loo.baz as baz


print(baz.greet())
```

foo/tests/test_bar.py:

```
import goo.koo.bar as b


def test_hello():
    assert b.hello() == "hello"
```

foo/tests/test_baz.py:

```
import goo.loo.baz as b


def test_greet():
    assert b.greet() == "the greeting is...hello"
```

foo/tests/test_file.py:

```
import os.path
import sys


def test_file():
    f = open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "tests", "data", "test.txt"), "rt")
    assert f.read() == "hello world"
```

When I go to the foo directory and run

```
python goo/run.py
```

this works.  But when I run

```
python -m pytest tests
```

I get the error

```
Traceback:
tests/test_baz.py:1: in <module>
    import goo.loo.baz as b
goo/loo/baz.py:1: in <module>
    from koo import bar
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'koo'
```

If I change baz.py to the following:

```
from goo.koo import bar


def greet():
    return "the greeting is..." + bar.hello()
```

then all the tests pass, but running the program gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "goo/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    import loo.baz as baz
  File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/foo/goo/loo/baz.py", line 1, in <module>
    from goo.koo import bar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'goo'
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742593/python3-pytest-directory-structure-and-imports) is similar, but does not have a marked answer.  One posted answer suggests moving the tests folder down, but this caused an issue on our build server, and also the common practice here seems to be to have the tests at the top level.

Assuming I want to keep the tests at the top level, is there any combination of imports that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a combination of absolute imports e.g. `from goo.koo import bar` and adding the folder foo to your PYTHONPATH with

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/foo
```

then structuring all your imports as if they are originating from the foo folder

Comment: This worked when running from the foo folder: PYTHONPATH=. python goo/run.py.  Another option that worked from the foo folder is python -m goo.run.